# Problems with Animation time (with ue4)

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, frame-rate

i'm using a UE4 mannequin model that i downloaded on web because it's a pain to reconstitute that mannequin bones since it was rigged on Maya. Problem is there was an animation inside that file with a length of 40 keyframes.
I deleted this anim, made my own anim (with a new length of 20 keyframes) but now when i want to EXPORT this animation, I still have my new animation but with the length of 40 frames (20first frames are good but 20 last are just no movement, copy pose of 20th frame)...

My setup : [image]

Maybe i forgot a parameter somewhere? Please help

The file was downloaded on [this link](https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/64458-asset-cross-compatible-blender-to-ue4-mannequin-rig) (there is 2 Rigs, one original(parented to other Rig bones) and another for animating)

Comment: maybe thats a stupid question, but did you try saving and restarting blender?
another thing to try would be to copy the mannequin with the animation into a new file and see if that works. (I know its tedious, but maybe it helps)

Comment: Yeah i already tried to save and reopen but not to copy the mannequin in another file, I'll try that. So it's a blender bug and not a mistake from me? (i forgot to say that the file was made for 2.7.x)

Comment: it certainly doesnt look like it's your fault from that screenshot.. ( A developer could tell you more if he had the file) I did run into weird bugs regularly when I was a beginner, and I still do. Especially now when I have to relearn for 2.8 - I suspect it has to do with how blender is programmed and uses cache data (if you have to use Ctrl+Z a lot / if you did weird or near-impossible operations), but I do not know and dont want to point fingers or something. maybe putting it into a new file helps, it most times that did it for me. Good Luck!

Comment: I tried to copy paste mesh + rig in a blank project but it doesn't work :( I made some test with an animation with 60 Frames and another with 20 Frames but both are recognized as 40 Frames by ue4... However if i make a new Mesh with a new rig and a quick animation, export to ue4 works perfectly.
Is there a way to "clear" completely the animation and remove all references to start on a new base?

Comment: I dont know.. I'm really sorry. Can you edit the animation in UE4 ? Cut the last 20 frames?

Comment: Yes i can but it's not convenient =/ I will use that until i find a fix

Comment: ok at least that.. maybe someone else will look at the problem if you append the blend-file?

Comment: I edited my original post to add the link of the file